# Is there a faster way of traveling between Indonesian islands than using the ferries?

Tags: indonesia, bali, lombok, scooters

I will be in Lombok in December 2016. During my trip I would like to visit other islands with a scooter (Bali, Nusa Penida, Nusa Lembogan, etc.)

I know that there is ferry but that is too slow (approx. 4 hours). So I would like to find a faster way to travel. What are my options?

Comment: I'm sure you could pay a small fortune and fly the scooter between islands. Otherwise there are fastboats between the islands -- approach any of the hundred odd operators and ask them how much extra to take your scooter with you.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas kinda late, but why not make that comment an answer? Seems perfectly valid for me.

Comment: @mts Because it was an extrapolation based on my own experiences. While I saw people use fastboot to get between islands I never saw anyone take a scooter. Nor did I actually take a fastboat between the islands listed (I only did Lombok-Gili Air-Bali.) I left it a comment in the hope that maybe someone had actually done the route in question since sea conditions would heavily influence the type of boat involved (and possibly even availability for particular routes.)

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @Roddy:

> I'm sure you could pay a small fortune and fly the scooter between islands. Otherwise there are fastboats between the islands -- approach any of the hundred odd operators and ask them how much extra to take your scooter with you.

So the solution is to go to the closet harbor and try your luck.